# Generating connection string for EF code first program

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm using code first approach with EF. Need to generate connection string from user input when program is started for first time.

Here's simple method to check if it can connect right now I'm trying to get some data because it happened that it was possible to open/close connection during test but getting any data was throwing exceptions:

```
public static bool IsConnectionValid(string connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString)) return false;
        using (var context = new HolidayCalendarContext(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Database.Connection.Open();
                var contex = context.Employees.ToList();
                context.Database.Connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now here I generate connection string, UserName and Password are optional, password may be provided as parameter later on:

```
private string GenerateConnectionString()
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = Source,
            InitialCatalog = Catalog,
            IntegratedSecurity = true,
            ConnectTimeout = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
        {
            builder.UserID = UserName;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password))
        {
            builder.Password = Password;
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

The method I test is an action bound to "Login to db" button. SaveConnection simply stores correct connection string in config file and ChangeUtility is just navigation stuff irrelevant at this point.

```
private void LoginToDatabaseExecute(object obj)
    {
        if (ValidateInput())
        {
            var connectionString = GenerateConnectionString();
            if (TestConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SaveConnection(connectionString);
                ChangeUtility(new LoginViewModel(MainViewModel));
            }
        }
    }
```

So I've got the test for generating those strings, the test passes. Checked with debugger, it connects and gets Employees correctly:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void SuccessfulConnectionStoresConnectionStringInSettings()
    {
        SetCorrectConnectionString();

        _viewModel.LoginToDatabaseCommand.Execute(null);

        var connectionString = SettingsHelper.GetConnectionString();

        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString));
    }

private void SetCorrectConnectionString()
    {
        _viewModel.Source = "YOGER\\SQLEXPRESS";
        _viewModel.Catalog = "HolidayCalendar";
        _viewModel.UserName = "";
        _viewModel.Password = "";
    }
```

And here's the problem. After test passed I launched program, set the same input, got *identical* connection string as from the test `"Data Source=YOGER\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=HolidayCalendar; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=5"` but connection failed at the point where IsConnectionValid tries to open it, throwing `"Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'." System.ArgumentException`

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll
```

I've been already tried `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` but it required Metadata, which I found code first doesn't have so I coulnd't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect to a SQL Express, but the exception is thrown from `SqlServerCe.dll`. It indicates, that your program uses the provider for SQL CE.

I would check `entityFramework.defaultConnectionFactory` section in your app.config` file. For SQL Express it should be set to

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That fixed the problem completely :]

Answer (score 0):

Exception thrown:

> 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Exception thrown:

> 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll

means till you are point out on SQL Server CE database not on SQL Server Express